# Да: там же, где и в прошлый раз

Tags: пунктуация

Можете сказать, можно ли вот так ставить после *да* двоеточие, как это в примере показано? (Или можно только запятую или точку после *да* ставить в данном случае?) Скажите, правильны ли все четыре варианта.

1. – Встретимся? Если да, то где?

– Да: там же, где и в прошлый раз.

2. – Встретимся? Если да, то где?

– Да, там же, где и в прошлый раз.

3. – Встретимся? Если да, то где?

– Да. Там же, где и в прошлый раз.

4. – Встретимся? Если да, то где?

– Да; там же, где и в прошлый раз.

Comment: "А именно" должно подходить, когда двоеточие.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

• После "да" можно поставить не только запятую или точку, но и восклицательный знак или многоточие (в зависимости от контекста) — для передачи эмоций, "нервенности" разговора.

Спокойный утвердительный ответ (с запятой):
*— Да, там же, где и в прошлый раз.*

Четкий или отрывистый (с точкой):
*— Да. Там же, где и в прошлый раз.*

Неуверенный, задумчивый, растерянный (с многоточием):
*— Да... Там же, где и в прошлый раз.*

Громкий ответ, эмоциональный, выражающий сильное чувство, душевное волнение (с восклицательным знаком):
*— Да! Там же, где и в прошлый раз.*

• Но чаще всего в ответной реплике после "да" вообще нет никакого знака ("да" в этом случае выступает в роли усилительной частицы, фраза звучит экспрессивно и является ответом сразу на оба вопроса; можно в конце и восклицательный знак поставить):
*— Да там же, где и в прошлый раз!*

Вы — автор, вам и знаки в руки. Вот только двоеточие и точка с запятой, мне кажется, здесь никак не подходят.

Comment: После "вы" точно тире? А то части по ритму не соответствуют друг другу, как бы надо: *Вы Автор, вам и знАки в руки.* Ударение на "вы" не в тему.

Comment: Это *мой* ответ. Это *мое* ви́денье: мой ритм, мое соответствие, мои ударения. *Вы — автор взгляда, идеи, мировоззрения, терпимости, вы ушли от местечковости, как мы все время уходим от мелкого противостояния* (С. Н. Есин). *Господин премьер-министр, вы — автор идеи Северного измерения* (П. Липпонен). *Она может захотеть многого, — выдохнул Нолик и закричал: — Но вы — автор!* (Г. Щербакова). *Ты — автор моего жизненного девиза и могильной надписи...* (М. Цветаева).

Comment: Просто по смыслу: *Раз вы автор, вам и знаки в руки.* Это логично, естественно. Вы не это задумывали? У вас же: *Вы являетесь автором, вам и знаки в руки.* То есть вы говорите человеку, кто он, будто он не знает, что он автор. Не логично, не естественно и странно.